# my question is how to take input from user in below code.. i got error in this code (missing 1 required positional argument)

Tags: python

[my question is how to take input from user in below code.I got error in this code (missing 1 required positional argument).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HO1oz.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1):

First consider copy and paste the code here instead of sending a link to image.
Then, your problems is that you are not passing the variable you called balance inside your functions that need to have a parameter.

so in line 19 instead of writing `cust.deposit()`, write this instead `cust.deposit(balance)` or `cust.deposit(55)`.

Of course you need first to create an object of account in the right way. i.e. creating it with parameters it needs and that you defined in the class. e.g.

```py
cust = Account(acno, name, balance)
```

and then: have your functions, e.g.:

```py
cust.deposit(55)
```

Comment: First time I am using stack over flow.. I don't have any idea about how to format code that's why I post code image, that time I am not able to ask the question so that I post screenshot..

Comment: Please guide me, how do i ask the question and how do i format the code in SOF.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass your variables as arguments to Account() as they are expected in the init.

Try

```
cust1 = Account(acno, name, balance)
```

and then

```
cust1.deposit(50)  # or any other amount
```